# does the timer thread wait till all the steps in the callback function are done or does the callback function get reinvoked in every period

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I have a timer thread function

```
SampleTimer = new Timer(SomeTask,0,70000)
```

call back function is as below

```
void SomeTask(object o)
{
//block using autoresetevent
}
```

The issue is the SomeTask() callback method gets called every 70 secs even though all the operations in the callback method is still not done.
How can I prevent the timer from calling the SomeTask() function before all the steps within it are completed

Comment: "the timer" - I'm aware of 3 classes/components in the framework called `Timer`, and they may all have different behaviour. Can you please identify which one you're referring to (by e.g. namespace)?

Comment: So what you what to do when timer fires again, ignore it? or queue it for later execution?

Comment: Meh.. if the problem is multiple invocations, why not just Sleep() loop it.  Trivial, no possibility of concurrent runs.  Why does everyone seem use timers when it is not appropriate?

Comment: @MartinJames: Because timers are almost always preferable to tying up a thread with a `Sleep`. In this case, a timer *is* appropriate, and preventing concurrent ticks is simple. A thread with a `Sleep` loop is typically a sign of a poor design. See [Programs are not cats](http://blog.mischel.com/2013/02/01/programs-are-not-cats/).

Comment: @JimMischel - it's a not-ready thread, so it's dead code.  Who cares much, even in a managed app?  Using a timer when there is the possibility of unwanted multiple-invocations is a sign of inappropriate design.  If you use a Sleep() loop, preventing concurrent ticks is not simple - it's inherent, a non-issue.

Comment: @MartinJames: If you say so. You can't interrupt a sleep. I'd hate to be the one that wants to tell the thread to stop, though, and have to wait 70 seconds because calling `Thread.Abort` might kill the thread while it's in the middle of doing something important. Additionally, timers scale. Having thousands of timers is trivial. On the other hand, every thread costs a megabyte, minimum, and will be occupying your address space regardless of whether it's doing something. But, hey ... it's your program. Knock yourself out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you're using a `System.Threading.Timer`.

One way to do it is to create the timer as a one-shot, and then restart it after the thread has completed its task. That way you're certain that you won't have any overlap:

```
myTimer = new Timer(someMethod, null, 70000, Timeout.Infinite);
```

And in your callback:

```
void TimerCallback(object o)
{
    // do stuff here
    // then change the timer
    myTimer.Change(70000, Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

Specifying `Timeout.Infinite` for the period disables periodic signaling, turning the timer into a one-shot.

Another way is to use a monitor:

```
object TimerLock = new object();

void TimerCallback(object o)
{
    if (!Monitor.TryEnter(TimerLock))
    {
        // already in timer. Exit.
        return;
    }

    // do stuff

    // then release the lock
    Monitor.Exit(TimerLock);
}
```

If you're wondering why I don't use a `try/finally` for the lock, see Eric Lippert's blog, [Locks and exceptions do not mix](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/06/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix.aspx).

The primary difference in these two approaches is that in the first the timer will fire 70 seconds after the previous callback execution finishes. In the second the timer will fire on a 70 second period, so the next callback might execute any time after the previous one finishes, from one second later to 70 seconds later.

For most things I've done, the first technique I showed seems to work better.

Comment: Never seen `Monitor` before.  Neat.

Comment: You should write "myTimer.Change(70000, Timeout.Infinite)" in finally block so that in case of exception it will run next time.

Comment: @SumitJoshi are you sure about that? If your timer callback throws an exception, are you sure that your program is still in a consistent state? Do you really want another callback after the first one throws an exception? You *can* do that, but it's always a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Concurrent invocations are possible which is a very annoying property of .NET and Windows timers. You have to ensure mutual exclusion yourself, maybe just using a lock (no events necessary). That gives you another problem though because if the timer ticks too fast an arbitrary number of threads might queue up in front of the lock. So it is better to `TryEnter` the lock and do nothing if it cannot be entered. You loose one tick that way but as ticks are not guaranteed anyway your application must be able to cope with that.

When working with timers very little is ever guaranteed about the time, count and concurrency of ticks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `object o` *is* the timer being fired.  So you may be able to do:

```
var myTimer = object as Timer;
```

(but I would check on that...)

It will fire on your interval no matter how long your `SomeTask` takes.

I always do something like this

```
private System.Timers.Timer _timer;

public static void main()
{
    _timer = SampleTimer = new Timer(SomeTask,0,70000);
}

void SomeTask(object o)
{
    _timer.Enabled = false;
    try{
    // ...  work...
    }finally{
        _timer.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

UPDATE: a bit safer with a lock.

```
private static object _padLock = new object();

void SomeTask(object o)
{
    // lock around disabling the timer
    lock(_padLock)
    {
        // return if some other thread beat us to it.
        if (!_timer.Enabled) return;
        _timer.Enabled = false;
    }

    try{
    // ...  work...
    }finally{
        _timer.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

To be super duper safe.  And if you only ever want one instance of "SomeTask" running.  AND, you don't want them to queue up.  You should put a lock() in SomeTask.  And you can skip disabling the timer.

Comment: This trick does not prevent concurrent modifications because any number of threads can arrive simultaneously on `_timer.Enabled = false`. In fact you are using the Timer instance concurrently which is not thread-safe.

Comment: The question wasn't about multiple timers firing the same delegate.  The question was about a long running task.  It could be made safer with a lock, but that depends on the OP's goal.  Perhaps multiple fires of different timers *is* OK. In which case, they should cast the object to a Timer and disable/enable that.

Comment: The same timer can fire the given delegate concurrently. This is actually what happens in the OPs case. This code only works if you assume "well-meaning" thread scheduling.

Comment: Still the `Enabled = true` call can happen concurrently with `Enabled = false` :)

Comment: The lock protects `_timer.Enabled = false`.  If another thread happens to enter `SomeTask` before the _timer has been disabled, it will wait for the lock then return because of the `if(!_timer.Enabled) return;`

The OP is dealing with one timer.  So this solves that problem.
If there were multiple timers then it's a different question because they may want to allow simultaneous execution of different timers.  In that case, I'd need to actually use `object o` as the timer to disable/enable.  And possibly different locks for each.  But the lock should be fast enough to not matter.

Comment: Hm true. The only problem I can find now is that Enabled can be concurrently read and written which is not defined to be safe. It starts to get nitpicky now though.