# C# ConcurrentDictionary vs. ManualResetEvent for Thread Control

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a Windows Service which uses a System.Threading.Timer with a callback to update endpoints like so:

```
UpdateEndpointTimer = new Timer(
                new TimerCallback(UpdateSBEndpoints),
                Endpoint.Statuses.Online,
                EndpointUpdateFrequency,
                EndpointUpdateFrequency);
```

Here is what my update method roughly looks like:

```
private void UpdateSBEndpoints(object state)
{
    ...
    using (var context = new TestHarnessContext())
    {
        var endpoints = context.Endpoints.Where(p =>
            p.Binding == Endpoint.Bindings.ServiceBus
            && p.State == Endpoint.States.Enabled
            && p.Status != status).ToList();

         foreach (var endpoint in endpoints)
         {
             //Do stuff here
         }
         ...
}
```

Now as the timer uses threads from the ThreadPool to fire callbacks, I need measures to control the threads. One specific problem occurs when multiple threads can grab the same endpoint from the db before the first thread to get it finishes work, and this results in duplicate work done in the foreach loop.

I know two possible solutions to the problem and I wonder which one is better and preferable to use. The solutions are `ConcurrentDictionary` and `ManualResetEvent`.

In the first case I would put this inside my foreach loop to ensure only one thread at a time can operate on a given endpoint:

```
if (EndpointsInAction.TryAdd(endpoint.Id, endpoint.Id) == false)
    // If we get here, another thread has started work with this endpoint.
    return;
...
//Do stuff with the endpoint, once done, remove its Id from the dictionary
...
int id;
EndpointsInAction.TryRemove(endpoint.Id, out id);
```

In the second case, I would control the threads like so:

```
protected ManualResetEvent PubIsBeingCreated { get; set; }
protected ManualResetEvent SubIsBeingCreated { get; set; }
...
this.PubIsBeingCreated = new ManualResetEvent(true);
this.SubIsBeingCreated = new ManualResetEvent(true);
...
foreach (var endpoint in endpoints)
{
   if (!this.PubIsBeingCreated.WaitOne(0))
// If we get here, another thread has started work with this endpoint.
        return;

   try
   {
       // block other threads (Timer Events)
       PubIsBeingCreated.Reset();
       // Do stuff
   }
   ...
   finally
   {
       // Restore access for other threads
       PubIsBeingCreated.Set();
   }
}
```

Now as both methods seem to work **I would like to know which one is preferable to use** (more efficient?). I lean towards using `ConcurrentDictionary` as it allows finer filtering of threads, i.e. no two threads are allowed to work with a specific endpoint vs. no two threads are allowed to work with a specific endpoint *type* (pubs and subs in ManualResetEvents). There might be another solution superior to mine, so any information will be appreciated.

Comment: Simply set the timer's *period* argument to 0.  Call Change() at the end of your method to restart it.  Now it never overlaps.

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, the timer is firing a second time before the first callback is complete. You can prevent that by using the technique I describe in the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996147/does-the-timer-thread-wait-till-all-the-steps-in-the-callback-function-are-done/17997283#17997283

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In no case should you use `ManualResetEvent` for this purpose. It's always better to use objects that provide higher-level abstractions, but even if you wanted to control this at a low level, using .NET's Monitor class (via the `lock` statement, and the `Monitor.Wait()` and `Monitor.Pulse()` methods would be better than using `ManualResetEvent`.

You seem to have a reasonably standard producer/consumer scenario. In that case, it seems to me that rather than a `ConcurrentDictionary`, you would be better off with `ConcurrentQueue`. Your producer would enqueue things, while your consuming threads would dequeue them for processing.

Comment: I should have provided more details about the update method. Basically, it periodically searches the DB for unprocessed endpoints, and when it finds them, creates Service Bus publishers and subscribers depending on the endpoint type. I think I see what you mean, but now I wonder how to deal with looping an update. If I were to abandon the timer (which is inherently multithreaded with no control over threads provided), what would be the best way to retain the automatic update functionality? Regardless, thanks a lot for discouraging using ManualResetEvent.

Comment: I don't see any need to abandon the use of the timer. It's not clear to me from the original post why you have concurrent processing of the updates. But assuming Hans' inference that it's because the timer elapses faster than it takes to process a single timer event, then his suggestion should work. Alternatively, you could just make the interval longer (while still synchronizing, in case you do get concurrent processing of the event).

Answer (score 0):

I would do it differently; I'd use the ConcurrentBag and have a single thread load it from the DB with multiple threads listening to it via TryTake. The single thread loading the bag will take care of your issue where they could potentially pick up the same item from the DB. The below will illustrate it in a console app:

```
class Program
{
    private static ConcurrentBag<int> _bag;

    public static void Main()
    {
        // Construct and populate the ConcurrentBag
        _bag = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
        var bagPopulateTask = new Task(PopulateBag);
        bagPopulateTask.Start();

        var bagEmptyTask1 = new Task(EmptyBag);
        var bagEmptyTask2 = new Task(EmptyBag);
        var bagEmptyTask3 = new Task(EmptyBag);

        bagEmptyTask1.Start();
        bagEmptyTask2.Start();
        bagEmptyTask3.Start();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void EmptyBag()
    {
        int i;
        while (true)
        {
            if (_bag.TryTake(out i))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} took {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, i);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} took nothing", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }
    }

    private static void PopulateBag()
    {
        var i = 0;

        while (i < 1000)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} added {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, i);
            _bag.Add(i);
            i++;
            Thread.Sleep(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that if order is important, you can do similar with a ConcurrentQueue or a ConcurrentStack.